# how to do batch file execute script in folders and subfolders?

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, cmd

I am creating a batch file that convert files (jpg, png, gif) and output new file on some folder where I find it. I ask to user to path of files, so the script needs scan directories and sub directories and executing script, but when the script enter in other folder, the script stops work...

Here my batch file:

```
set /p folderScan=Enter folder path:

cd %folderScan%

call :searchInFolder
goto :eof

:searchInFolder
for %%f in (*.png *.jpg *.gif) do (
    "%~dp0\myconverter.exe" "%CD%\%%f" -o "%CD%\%%~nf.newextension"
)

for /D %folderScan% in (*) do (
    cd %%d
    :searchInFolder
)

pause
```

When the script enter in **for /D**... and finds a folder and accesses it, the files that are inside that folder are not processed by the script ...

I need to scan all folders and subfolders, when I finish processing the files inside one folder, I need to move to the next folder, and if the folder has folders inside, the folder that has been accessed, the script needs access to it too and process the files, like this:

```
|D:\Desktop\Images
|_Car
|__Red
|__Blue
|___Dark Blue
|_Bike
|_Animals
|__Dog
|__Cat
|_Games
|__Race
|___Bike
|___Cars
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need two different `for` loops (one for folders the other one for files). `for /R` can handle files recursively:

```
for /R "%folderScan%" %%f in (*.png *.jpg *.gif) do ( 
  "%~dp0\myconverter.exe" "%%~ff" -o "%%~dpnf.newextension"
)
```